# meaning of "one aside"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "one aside" here mean ***"I, as a participant, ..."*** or ***"apart from this, ..."***?

> Later, tumbling down the main steps of Tate Britain as we head first
>   for Lambeth Bridge, the city is awash with the wail of sirens and
>   clacking of helicopter rotor blades.A state of emergency. Chaos,
>   disruption and, above all, noise accompany us all the way. The artist
>   can barely make himself heard at times. **One aside** I manage to catch as
>   we set off: ‘everything you see and hear in the city is the
>   consequence of a decision. Cities are made by humans, every bit’.

Answer (score 2):

I think *aside* is to be taken as a noun:

> - a comment spoken by a character in a play that is heard by the audience but is supposedly not heard by other characters on stage
> - a comment that is spoken quietly to someone so that it cannot be heard by other people who are present
> - a comment or discussion that does not relate directly to the main subject being discussed

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aside

I.e., the quoted text is the single fragment of speech that the *I* managed to catch.

Comment: this, definitely.